# How to color legend in angular-chart.js

Tags: angularjs, charts, typescript, chart.js

the very last example in [this section](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#directives) of angular-chart.js documentation shows a pie/polar chart example with a colored legend. Obviously, this should be my answer, but:

I used this code for my frontend (which is pretty much the same as in the doc):

```
<canvas id="base" 
        class="chart-pie" 
        chart-type="type" 
        chart-data="data" 
        chart-labels="labels" 
        chart-legend="true">
</canvas>
```

I did also use the same data and labels. But unfortunately the legend of the rendered plot consists out of list-bullet-points and the labels (see enclosed image) This happens to all charts I create with this library.
Does anybody know this behavior or (even better) any solution for that problem?

I am using angular/typescript and bound the DefinitelyTyped file to my project.

[image: my angular-chart.js plot]

EDIT: I am not willing to define any colors by myself! The chart gets its own colors by itself. We should leave it like that.

Comment: It seems you are missing the reference to a style sheet in your html file `angular-chart.css`

Comment: Ha! At first I want to write 'I am afraid not.' And I didn't (forget), but did misspell the path to my bower components. Thanks for the hint, you @cleftheris definitely made my day!

Comment: Take a look at this question, maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107708/render-a-legend-on-angular-chart-js-doughnut-chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing the reference to a style sheet in your html file. `angular-chart.css`

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js.git
$ npm install
$ bower install
```

Then open angular-chart.js\examples\charts.html

Change

```
<canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie chart-xs" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
```

to

```
<canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie chart-xs" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true"></canvas>
```

And the chart has a legend with colors. Your CSS seems to be different than the one in official distribution.