# Render a legend on angular-chart.js doughnut chart

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I've followed angular-chart.js documentation, and created a chart, but am unable to render a legend with it. I don't understand why its not working.

Documentation: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ 
Similar SO question: [How to color legend in angular-chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614469/how-to-color-legend-in-angular-chart-js)

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="CircleCtrl" style="display: block;">
    <div class="chart-container" style="width:400px; height:200px;">
        <canvas id="doughnut"
            class="chart chart-doughnut"
            chart-data="data"
            chart-labels="labels"
            chart-colours="colours"
            chart-legend="true">
        </canvas> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I've also tried defining an array for legend in the controller,

```
$scope.legend = ["complete", "incomplete"]
```

Per the accepted answer in the other SO question, `chart-legend="true"` should be enough to make it work.

Does anyone have experience with this library and have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 48):

If you're using the 1.0.0-alpha branch based on chart.js 2, the correct syntax is:

```
$scope.options = {legend: {display: true}};
```

and in your html

```
<canvas id="pie"
            class="chart chart-pie"                
            chart-data="data"
            chart-labels="labels"
            chart-options="options">
 </canvas>
```

Comment: The legend appears on top, and affects the size of the pie. Is there any way to place it below?

Comment: Yes, you can set options in your controller: $scope.options.legend.position:"bottom"; you can find all the info here : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration

Answer (score 2):

I had Similar Problem So I have extended the width of the Pie Chart and Placed Legends Right Side of the Graph and Looks Pretty Well

You can add this in the Controller

```
 $scope.options = {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right'
    }
  };
```

In HTML you can add

```
<canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-series="series" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-colors="colors" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride">
        chart-series="series"
      </canvas>
```

[image: This How it Looks Like]